# jsPDF method to save a file doesn’t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jspdf

I’ve already spent four days trying to solve a question that, at the beginning, seemed quite a child’s game: using a jsPDF library I’m trying to save a file. Not to print it, that’s something already done.

So here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="offline.appcache">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<title>New project</title>

<!-- Allow fullscreen mode on iOS devices. (These are Apple specific meta tags.) -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="256x256" href="icon-256.png" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />

<!-- Chrome for Android web app tags -->
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="256x256" href="icon-256.png" />

<script src="script/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/libs/base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/libs/sprintf.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jspdf.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>               
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/FileSaver.js"></script>

 <!-- The CSS -->   
 <style type="text/css">
    p
    {
    font-size: 18px;

    }
    #container{
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    }
 </style>   

<!-- The javascript -->     
<script>
function print()
{
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
doc.output('datauri');
}

function save()
{
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
doc.save('nombre_example.pdf');
}

</script>
</head> 

<body> 

<input type="button" value="Print" height="50px" width="50px" Onclick="print()">
<input type="button" value="Save" height="50px" width="50px" Onclick="save()">
<div id="container">
    <p>
    HOLA <br>
    HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA     <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>HOLA <br>
    </p>
</div>

 </body> 
 </html>
```

Then, when I click the button 'save' I can read on the javacript console:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save' index.html:58`

The list of JavaScript files that I’ve attached to the project is:

1. FileSaver.js
2. jquery-2.1.0.min.js
3. jspdf.js
4. jspdf.plugin.addimage.js
5. jspdf.plugin.autoprint.js
6. jspdf.plugin.cell.js
7. jspdf.plugin.from_html.js
8. jspdf.plugin.javascript.js
9. jspdf.plugin.png_support.js
10. jspdf.plugin.sillysvgrenderer.js
11. jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js
12. jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js
13. jspdf.plugin.total_pages.js

and the libraries:

1. base64.js
2. sprintf.js

So, after showing all this info my question is: Why can’t I make the save button work properly?

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message seems to say it precisely. The `doc` object that you created with `new jsPDF()` doesn't have a `.save()` method. Presumably there is something in the documentation for jsPDF that describes how to enable saving, but since their web site requires contact information before allowing you to download the library, I'm not interested in investigating further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try Adding Only these Two Script files and see

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/FileSaver.js"></script>
```

and besides why are you adding jspdf.js file two times...